# What characters in Monsters Inc. have cameos in Monsters University?

Tags: monsters-inc, monsters-university

I loved Monsters University, but it was such a complex movie that I had trouble catching all of the characters from Monsters Inc. For instance, George Sanderson, the 'sock' guy from the first film, is in the JOX fraternity. We had hoped Jennifer Tilly would reprise her role as Celia, but we didn't find her.

Is there a canonical list of characters appearing in both films?

Comment: Have you looked at the IMDB listings?  Those often have full credits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No canonical list that I'm aware of (yet). But here's a list of the monsters that I've been able to cobble up. Feel free to edit and add more.

[image: Sulley]

- James P. Sullivan AKA Sulley: Main character.

[image: Mike]

- Mike Wazowski: Main character.

[image: Randall]

- Randall Boggs: Supporting character.

[image: Yeti]

- The Abominable Snowman: Mail room supervisor at Sulley's and Mike's first job.

[image: Roz]

- Roz: Number 0001 of the CDA clean up team.

### Non-speaking cameos:

[image: Mr. Waternoose]

- Mr. Waternoose: In one of the pictures in Mike's locker.

[image: George Sanderson]

- George Sanderson: Member of the Jaws Theta Chi (AKA JOX) fraternity, and in the Scarer card collection in the end of the film.

[image: Ricky]

- Ricky Plesuski: One of the students, and in the Scarer card collection in the end of the filme.

[image: Flint]

- Flint: Teaching Sully and Mike on the scaring simulator in Monsters Inc. during their Scarer tryouts near the end.

[image: Charlie]

- Charlie: On the Scare Floor when Sulley and Mike start their first day as Scarers.

[image: Waxford]

- Waxford: On the Scare Floor during Mike's school field trip, and during Team OK's sneak visit.

Comment: Fungus, Randall's assistant is seen handling from a chandelier in the first party

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 references to Celia. At the end, in Mike's locker, there is a post-it note that says "call me 555 555 Celia" with the lipstick mark and a black and white picture of her.

Comment: This is nice as an addition to an answer or a comment, but by itself does not answer the question. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of how to ask and answer questions here. We're not a typical discussion forum. Please don't be discouraged, we were all new here at some point.